# Express JS performance issue

Tags: mongodb, performance, express, performance-testing, load-testing

I have built a full-fledged backend using express js and MongoDB(using Mongoose) for a MERN stack application where the frontend is hosted using NginX and the backend routes are reverse proxied.

I performed load testing on my single instance of express server using K6 testing package.
In the test, I just ran 3-4 APIs like login,fetch dashboard data, etc and kept the virtual user count as 200.

In the Test result, I got maximum 49 requests per second and 90 percentile response time of around 9 seconds for single request which is very slow.

I tried hosting the MongoDB on the same server and a different cluster in the same region to reduce network lag and throttling(Earlier i was using Atlas free tier). also tried hosting it on a fresh quad core server but there was a very little performance gain.

I want to increase single thread performance to reduce server cost as it will require less nodes in a cluster.

Is there any way to improve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure there's a ton of debugging information to go off of here. Sounds like you've ruled out network latency (between app and db) which is good. But is database itself performing well? What profiling (app and db) have you done to determine where the bottleneck is? Without knowing what is slow it's kind of impossible to advise on how to make it faster